# How to switch between portrait and landscape mode with libGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, landscape-portrait

I've created a game that is working well in desktop mode. But when I run it in mobile, it runs in landscape mode only. How can I make the game work successfully in both portrait and landscape mode?

Comment: I lightly edited the title to make it a bit clearer just what you need, and fixed up the grammar and phrasing in the body to get to the point a little faster. Finally, I added a useful tag to improve visibility.

Comment: As much as i remember, you need to modify the AndroidManifest.xml (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-&-configuration#the-androidmanifestxml-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the screenOrientation to fullSensor in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
```

This will detect the orientation of the device and rotate the screen automatically. Also ViewPorts in LibGDX are used to determine how your program will handle the width and height changes when the screen rotates. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Answer (score 1):

Open AndroidManifest.xml located in Android project and find the entry that says:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Change "landscape" to "portrait" to make it look like this:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```